# Weird Wubi.exe installation?

Tags: wubi, password

I would like to get Ubuntu on my old laptop (HP Compaq). So I ran the installation and it completed (I installed 13.04 with the Wubi installer). When I booted it up, it went to the login screen. This part gets weird: instead of it saying my username with a password box under it, it says Login: with a box under it. I type in my username and password and it says failed! It also says "localhost.localdomain" in the corner. I didn't install the server version of Ubuntu and im typing in the right username and password but it keeps saying failed. I can go to guest account but I can hardly do anything. I cant even configure my wireless settings! And for some reason Ubuntu corrupted Windows 7 that was on the computer because when I try to hit the option Windows 7 it says "starting windows" and that's it.
What do I do? Is there a way without reinstalling Ubuntu? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
                                                                   -Inky
```

Answer (score 0):

For resolving the login issue you should be able to go into recovery mode and use "adduser " then "sudo adduser  sudo" to create another account.

Comment: I don't have the Grub bootloader so I cant do that.

Comment: when it starts to chain load into ubuntu, press shift and it will display the grub menu. You have it it just isn't showing as you have the windows bootloader chainload into it

Comment: I tried pressing SHIFT. Nothing happens except loud beeping sounds.

Comment: how long did you hold it?

Comment: I held it the whole time.

Comment: until it booted ubuntu? and when did you start holding it?

Comment: When I pressed "Ubuntu" from Windows Boot Manager

Comment: try pressing it right before you press that

Comment: Nope. Nothing happened.

Comment: and there is no advanced options selection when you turn on the computer?

Comment: Nope. Just a regular boot up.